# SQL UDF in WHERE condition

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions

I want to write a query kind of like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DupFinder
@FirstName varchar(20),
@LastName varchar(20)

AS

SELECT CustId 
  FROM Cust c 
 WHERE [dbo].[fn_MatchConfidence](@FirstName + ' ' + @LastName,
                                  [dbo].fn_createCustHash (CustId)) > .8
```

Running the fn_MatchCondifence User-Defined Function (which takes two varchars and returns a number) over the entire Cust table. CreateCustHash just makes a string of FirstName and LastName with a space in the middle.

How can I do this?

Comment: And what error are you getting exactly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use a Scalar function. They're really bad.

http://msmvps.com/blogs/robfarley/archive/2009/12/05/dangers-of-begin-and-end.aspx

Instead, use an inline table-valued function.

Comment: +1: Yep - indexes, gone on outermost query.  Probably doing god knows within it...

Comment: Not that... the problem is that the function will be executed in a different context. Look in Profiler and you'll see the engine start a different execution context for each function call.